# How do I render screens according to state variables?

Tags: javascript, react-native

*UPDATE*

Someone helpfully suggested chaining ternary statements in the answers below, but I'm afraid this doesn't work. I've copied my version of their solution below. The error is  `Error: A navigator cannot contain multiple 'Screen' components with the same name (found duplicate screen named 'Welcome')`

```
// This is the root stack navigator.
// It is currently the main skeleton of the navigation logic

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

const RootStackScreen = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);

  const [hasCompletedIntro, setHasCompletedIntro] = React.useState(false);
  const [hasSelectedLanguage, setHasSelectedLanguage] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator>
      {hasSelectedLanguage ? (
        <>
          <RootStack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
          <RootStack.Screen
            name="HowToUseThisApp"
            component={HowToUseThisAppScreen}
          />
          <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={AppTabsScreen} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="Choose Your Language"
          component={ChooseYourLanguageScreen}
        />
      )}
      {!hasCompletedIntro && hasSelectedLanguage ? (
        <>
          <RootStack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
          <RootStack.Screen
            name="HowToUseThisApp"
            component={HowToUseThisAppScreen}
          />
          <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={AppTabsScreen} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={AppTabsScreen} />
      )}
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

---

Our app uses React Native 0.63.2 and React Navigation v5. We are using functional components with hooks only, no classes.

I need to find a way to render the following screens according to the following pieces of state, so:

- if hasSelectedLanguage AND hasCompletedIntro are both true, they should go to the HomeScreen.
- hasSelectedLanguage is true but hasCompletedIntro is false, they should go to the WelcomeScreen.
- hasSelectedLanguage is false, they should go to the ChooseYourLanguageScreen.

As you can see in the code snippet, I have already found a way to render screens according to the boolean state of `hasCompletedIntro`, but React Navigation 5 throws errors when I try to chain ternary statements. I'm stuck.

I would love to know how to render screens to account for the bullet points above while also retaining the navigation associated with the `hasCompletedIntro` ternary which is already in the code.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import WelcomeScreen from '../screens/WelcomeScreen';
import AppMenuScreen from '../screens/AppMenuScreen';
import HowToUseThisAppScreen from '../screens/HowToUseThisAppScreen';
import ChooseYourLanguageScreen from '../screens/ChooseYourLanguageScreen';

// This is the tab navigator for the bottom tabs containing the Home and More stack navigators

const AppTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

const AppTabsScreen = () => {
  return (
    <AppTabs.Navigator
      AppTabsBarOptions={{
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 15,
          fontWeight: '600',
          marginBottom: 8,
        },
      }}>
      <AppTabs.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <AppTabs.Screen name="App Menu" component={AppMenuScreen} />
    </AppTabs.Navigator>
  );
};

// This is the root stack navigator.
// It is currently the main skeleton of the navigation logic

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

const RootStackScreen = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);

  const [hasCompletedIntro, setHasCompletedIntro] = React.useState(false);
  const [hasSelectedLanguage, setHasSelectedLanguage] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator>
      {hasCompletedIntro ? (
        <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={AppTabsScreen} />
      ) : (
        <>
          <RootStack.Screen
            name="Choose Your Language"
            component={ChooseYourLanguageScreen}
          />
          <RootStack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
          <RootStack.Screen
            name="HowToUseThisApp"
            component={HowToUseThisAppScreen}
          />
          <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={AppTabsScreen} />
        </>
      )}
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStackScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: " but React Navigation 5 throws errors when I try to chain ternary statements." Show the code that you tried and what the errors are.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've updated the post with the error. Thank you!

Comment: The problem with the code from your edit is that the conditions are not mutually exclusive, so more than one welcome screen is rendered. In fact, the conditions in your code don't match what you describe in the prose of your question. If you line those up, then it will work as you want.

Comment: See my completely revamped answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems with your attempt to chain ternary operators:

1. The conditions are not mutually exclusive so the same screen is rendered multiple times.
2. The same screen is rendered in the "else" branch of multiple ternary operators.

The solution is to remove this duplication.

The simplest approach is to make sure all conditions are mutually exclusive and that each "else" branch rendereds a unique screen. Right now your conditions are `hasSelectedLanguage` and `!hasCompletedIntro && hasSelectedLanguage` which can both be true at the same time. Insead, you could change them to `hasCompletedIntro && hasSelectedLanguage` and `!hasCompletedIntro && hasSelectedLanguage` which cannot be both true at the same time (and matches your verbal description anyway).

One solution is to nest the ternary operators so that only one branch executes:

```
{ <condition1> ? <screens> : (<condition2> ? <screens> : <screens>)}
```

But with when you fill this out with the actual JSX, the nesting and indentation will be horrendous. Instead, I suggest using JavaScript code before the `return`:

```
render() {
    let screens = <default screens>;
    if (<condition1>) {
        screens = <screens>;
    } else if (<condition2>) {
        screens = <screens>;
    }

    return (
        <RootStack.Navigator>
            {screens}
        </RootStack.Navigator>
    ;
}
```

The `if` logic can be whatever you want to get the job done. This cleanly separates that logic from the actual rendering.

Comment: Hello, thanks for having a go! Unfortunately it doesn't work. Adding an edit now